# Countdown Timer in iOS according to elapsed time

Tags: ios, xcode

I have found quite a few questions & answers here regarding implementing a Countdown timer in iOS but none have answered my question yet.

What I want to do is when the user presses a button, it saves the exact time he pressed it and counts down 6 hours.
I made the NSTimer to fire a method that calculates every 1 second if the counter reached the future end time and displays it accordingly on the Counter.

What I tried to do so far is save the exact time the user pressed the button while finding out the time its supposed to end the countdown (in milliseconds) stored in a variable named futureTime and than comparing the two (startTime and futureTime).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    sixHours = 21600000;
}


- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    [self setStartTime];
    [timer invalidate];
    secondsLeft = sixHours;
    futureTime = self.startTime + sixHours;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    NSTimeInterval currentTimeInMilliseconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    if (currentTimeInMilliseconds == futureTime) {
        [timer invalidate];
        self.counterLabel.text = @"Done!";
    } else {
        secondsLeft -= 1000;
        self.counterLabel.text = [self formatTimeStamp:secondsLeft];
    }
}

- (void)setStartTime {
    NSTimeInterval currentTimeInMilliseconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    self.startTime = currentTimeInMilliseconds;
}
```

Obviously, it's not working very well, and it's not accurate.

Any suggestions? or a better approach?

Thanks :)

Comment: You probably want to use something else since there's no guarantee your app will still be running 6 hours later and further the timer will not fire whilst the app is in background. Take a look at local notifications (UILocalNotification).

Comment: I will schedule a push notification to alert the user when the 6 hours are over.

Answer (score 0):

You only want a count down timer, in that case you can do as :

```
@implementation AppDelegate{
    NSTimer *timer;
    NSInteger totalSeconds;
}


-(void)showTime{
    NSLog(@"%ld",totalSeconds--);
    if (totalSeconds==0){
        NSLog(@"6 hours!!! Time over.");
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}


- (IBAction)countDown:(id)sender {
    totalSeconds = 6*60*60; //6 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: It's a simple approach, but it will not work, since the countdown would pause when the app goes into background... that's why I need to calculated time range.

Comment: @Pro5per: Oh if that is the case then you need to check other cases also, like phone is switched off. So I would suggest you to save the time in userdefaults and keep on polling once the app wakes from launch or becomes active.

Comment: True, but for that I need a way to calculate the time passed since the "startTime" I am storing in NSUserDefaults. This is where it gets tricky :(